# Localizing iOS App's "What's new in this version" via iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

So I localized my iOS App's description into several languages. Now, I wish to add a new version of the App. iTunesConnect seems to require me to enter this text separately for every language for which I have a description.

Does anybody know if I need to localize the description? If I just copy the same English text for each localization (without translating), will my update be rejected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update won't be rejected if you copy and paste the English text.

However, I would recommend getting the phrase "Various bug fixes" translated into your supported languages just so you can have something to put there. (that is, if you are usually fixing bugs, of course ;-).

Comment: Does anyone have a source for this translation?